# Are variables bounded to free variables still free variables?

Tags: variables, functional-programming, free-variable, bound-variable

I am looking at some questions in my textbook about whether or not the variables are free or bound. I am not sure about these two in particular.

First off, I want to make sure I understand the concept of free vs. bound. I am fairly sure this x is a free variable in the following:

`variable x is free in expression "x"`

I believe this is true but I just want to make sure.

These two questions I am not really sure about, however.

`(/ (+ 1 x) (let x 2 (+ x x)))`,
`(let x y (/ (+ 1 x) (let x 2 (+ x x))))`

For the top expression, the x in the first subexpression is unbound(right?) but x in the second subexpression is bound to 2, so would that mean the x in regards to the expression as a whole is unbound?

For the bottom expression, x is bound to y, but y is a free variable(?). So would x be free because y is free or is it bound because x is still bounded to y?

Answer (score 0):

> For `(/ (+ 1 x) (let x 2 (+ x x)))`, the `x` in the first subexpression is unbound but `x` in the second subexpression is bound to `2`, so would that mean the `x` in regards to the expression as a whole is unbound?

Yes. Although I would use the terminology "is bound" or "is free" only with respect to a concrete variable expression, not to a name. As you can see, it's ambiguous what "`x`" refers to.

I'd say "*the whole expression **has** a free variable `x`*", which is what you usually care about when trying to evaluate the expression.

> For `(let x y (/ (+ 1 x) (let x 2 (+ x x))))`, `x` is bound to `y`, but `y` is a free variable. So would `x` be free because `y` is free or is it bound because `x` is still bounded to `y`?

The `x` is bound (and can be substituted). `y` is free.